# Mura CMS- How to display extended attributes using attribute set name

Tags: coldfusion-11, mura

I have a couple attribute sets basically to display store hours. I have attribute set named as Sunday, Monday till Saturday. And each attribute set has 2 extended attribues named `open` and `close` which are dropdowns with values from 7 AM to 5 PM. since all the `open` and `close` attribute names will be same, I don't know how to access a particular day's (in my case attribute set) `open` and `close` fields.

E.g of what i am trying is

Attribute set name = `Sunday`

extended attribute name = `Open` -> values from 7AM to 5PM -> input `name=open`

extended attribute name = `Close` -> values from 7AM to 5PM -> input `name=close`

Attribute set name = `Monday`

extended attribute name = `Open` -> values from 7AM to 5PM -> input `name=open`

extended attribute name = `Close` -> values from 7AM to 5PM -> input `name=close`

and so on. All the `open` and `close` extended attributes have same name resp.

I want to know how to access a particular attribute set's `open` and `close` fields. I know I can keep the `Label` same and change `Name` but is there any way to access those with attribute set name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use unique names for extended attributes, even if they are in different attribute sets. Why don't you prefix the attribute with the day? mo_open, mo_close, tu_open, tu_close, ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did end up doing the same thing. prefixed with days. Thanks :)